# Phones back button press responds only after 3-5 times tap?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have an fragment inside activity, which has nested full-screen, they are made like nested screens so I am handling back press in my container activity as follows :

```
    @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); // first line where I have debug point
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
// If drawer is open then on backpress drawer will be closed
                } else {
                    if (docFragment != null && docFragment.isAdded()) {
                        if (docFragment.isNestedViewVisible() == View.VISIBLE) {
                             docFragment.closeNestedView();
        // Above method will hide the nested view in fragment 
        // & return back to original default view of fragment
                        } else {
                            super.onBackPressed();
                        }
                    } else {
                        super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The code using which I am adding a fragment :

```
docFragment = DocumentFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, docFragment, "Documents");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Some times phones back button don't have any effect. I have to press it 3-5 times. I ran the application in debugger but debugger also gets on first line after 3-5 times tap.

This is handled from activity.

But why is that my onBackPress event is getting fired after 3-5 times tapping, not in single click ?

**Update :**

User [Maik Peschutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4711653/maik-peschutter) below has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862486/phones-back-button-press-responds-only-after-3-5-times-tap/45863501#45863501) that my fragment may have some heavy process which may cause the onBackPress delivery to delay or not happen at all.

I investigated in that percepective it appeared that there was one service in background which was sending some signals ( Broadcasts ) which were causing my UI to redrawn, The component getting redrawn is complex and takes time.

The frequency of signals from background service was too much, in millisecods it caused the redrawn to happen rapidly which made my app freez, Now I have scheduled service to send the signal at an interval of 20 seconds. This solved my problem. Now the tap responds on first time & far more quickly than earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your application. Do a breakpoint in the first line of your onBackPressed() method in your activity. So you can be sure if the method gets invoked after the first tap on your phones back button or not.

If not, maybe the FragmentManager already handled the event and removes a fragment from backstack each time you tap on your button.

Maybe your docFragment.closeNestedView() method is very slow so that docFragment.isNestedViewVisible() is returning not View.VISIBLE right after you called docFragment.closeNestedView(). Hard to say without the code.

Comment: I had a debug point  on first line of onBackPressed() but the back button press doesn't happen to come there on first tap it takes 3-5 taps.

Comment: Then some other object like the FragmentManager consumes the event. How do you add your fragment? Could you add some code?

Comment: Also nested view back press works without delay,Its the main layout of fragment when visible & I am expecting the activity to close that event takes these may tapes to respond. Nested view for sure doesn't take time. But may be the main view of fragment has something time consuming.

Comment: Hey plz have look at the update section in question thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fragments, I think that you should take a look at `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()` and `popBackStack()` for a more reliable way to handle back button presses.

Maybe this link will help : 
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: Fragment is single & views are nested its not the fragment back stack issue its activity whose onBackPressed method is which gets called after 3-5 tapes to back button of phone.